# Dynamic Element with AngualrJS $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-compile

I am creating dynamic button and using $compile to bind ng-click event. I am adding two parameters there. Problem is that if the parameter is string and having space in between, Parameter is splitting.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var name 'Demo 1';
var str= 'hello'
var btnhtml = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click=getShops("' + str + '","' + name + '")>View Detail</button>';
temp = $compile(btnhtml)($scope);
```

Generated HTML code looks like following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ng-scope" ng-click="getData("hello","Demo" 1")>View Detail</button>
```

Where my desired output is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ng-scope" ng-click="getData("hello","Demo1")>View Detail</button>
```

How can I fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't escape html properly

```
btnhtml = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="getShops(\'' + str + '\',\'' + name + '\')">View Detail</button>';
```

I removed the double quote symbol `"` before the escape.

Comment: @Bhuneshwer did you get a chance to look at mine answer?

Comment: Yes  it helped me to solve my problem . I  removed " symbol before escape character.

Comment: @Bhuneshwer Glad to know that. Thanks ;)